# How are filters selected for convolutional neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

If I want to design a CNN, do I have to specify the filter type for each of the hidden layers?

Comment: There are trained layers with weights and usually pooling layers. The combination, the size, and the pooling method need to be defined in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify a filter type in CNNs, you just specify number of kernels (filters), dimensions of the filters, initial weights, number of layers, etc. 
The network then creates the suitable filter by training and changing its weights